# Simplifying user-input foolproofing, Python

Tags: python, user-input, simplify

I have the following code to make sure that a user enters a float in python:

```
while True:
    try:
        some_variable = int(input("Input Prompt: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a whole number (in digits)")
```

The code works fine, but I have a program that needs many of these, and I was wondering if there is a way to simplify it.

*ie I wouldn't have to use:*

```
while True:
    try:
        some_variable = int(input("Input Prompt: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a whole number (in digits)")
```

For every user input. I'd really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Use a function.

Comment: Ok, could you send a way to do that for all the inputs as an answer? Sorry, I am relatively new to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use https://github.com/asweigart/pyinputplus to specify what ranges or inputs are valid?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I prefer not to import, but this is still very useful.

Comment: Why? What is wrong with using imports and reusing code (created by you or others)?

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that wrongly, I meant to say that I prefer not to import where unnecessary so I can have more control over my code and get more coding experience.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did some research on Thierry Lathuille's suggestion. I used functions to simplify the code. Below is the simplified code for everyone's use:

```
def int_input(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            variable_name = int(input(prompt))
            return variable_name
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a whole number (in digits)")


def float_input(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            variable_name = float(input(prompt))
            return variable_name
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number (in digits)")


def yes_input(prompt):
    while True:
        variable_name = input(prompt).lower()
        if variable_name in ["y", "yes"]:
            return "yes"
        elif variable_name in ["n", "no"]:
            return "no"
        else:
            print("""Please enter either "yes" or "no":  """)


while True:
    print("Volume of a right circular cone")
    print("Insert the radius and height of the cone below:")
    one_third = 1 / 3
    radius = float_input("Radius: ")
    height = float_input("Perpendicular Height: ")
    pi_confirm = yes_input("""The value of π is 22/7, "yes" or "no": """)
    if pi_confirm == "yes":
        pi = 22/7
    if pi_confirm == "no":
        pi = float_input("Type the value of pi, for eg ➡ 3.141592653589: ")

    volume = one_third * pi * radius ** 2 * height
    accuracy = int_input("How many decimal places do you want your answer to?: ")
    print(f"""{volume:.{accuracy}f}""")
    new_question = yes_input("""New question? "yes" or "no": """)
    if new_question == "no":
        break
```

Again thanks for your help.
Also if anyone has any more suggestions for the code I'd really appreciate it if you leave a comment.